# How to solve invalid character in identifier error

Tags: python, datetime, discord.py

So I am making a discord bot ,
I saw this code on a stackoverflow question

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta    
now = datetime.now() # a datetime.datetime objekt 
last_claim_stamp = str(now.timestamp()) # save this into json
​last_claim=datetime.fromtimestamp(float(last_claim_stamp))

delta = now - last_claim # the timedelta between now and the last claim
​if delta > timedelta(hours=48): # if last claim is older than 48h; 24h until he can re use the command + 24h time to claim his daily money again = 48h
   ​streak = 1 # reset the streak
else:
   ​streak += 1          

@client.command()
@commands.check(user)
@commands.cooldown(1, 86400, commands.BucketType.user)
async def daily(ctx):
   ​with open("streak.json", "r") as f:
       ​data = json.load(f)
   ​streak = data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["streak"]
   ​last_claim_stamp = data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["last_claim"]
   ​last_claim = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(last_claim_stamp)
   ​now = datetime.now()
   ​delta = now - last_claim
   ​if delta > timedelta(hours=48):
       ​print("reset streak")
       ​streak = 1
   ​else:
       ​print("increase streak")
       ​streak += 1
   ​daily = 45 + (streak * 5)
   ​amount_after = data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["balance"] + daily
   ​data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["streak"] = streak
   ​data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["balance"] += daily
   ​data[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["last_claim"] = str(now.timestamp())
   ​with open("streak.json", "w") as f:
       ​json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
   ​embed = discord.Embed(title="Daily", colour=random.randint(0, 0xffffff), description=f"You've claimed your daily of **{daily}**, now you have **${amount_after}**")
   ​embed.set_footer(text=f"Your daily streak: {streak}")
   ​await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I got the error here -

```
File "main.py", line 1148
    ​last_claim=datetime.fromtimestamp(float(last_claim_stamp))
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

I retyped  code  the starting part where is the error but still no success please help.I used another interpreter , it showed the same error but at a different place i.e. `(last_claim_stamp)`

Comment: Post a [example]. In your example code there's no line 1148.

Comment: You're missing a `)` on that line.

Comment: Actually that typo is on the copy of the line in the function.

Comment: I can see the error using both the pasted code and the pasted error message, so that's sufficient to answer the question?

Comment: @Barmar I am not missing any `)`  you may have missed it

Comment: `last_claim = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(last_claim_stamp)` is missing a `)` at the end.

Comment: i dont know I edited it but it is not showing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has an invisible Unicode character at the beginning of the name `last_claim`, specifically U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE

Indeed, the whole section of code seems to have U+200B characters at the beginning of most lines.

How to resolve this depends more on your editor / IDE than Python; you will need to figure out how to do a search and replace to remove them all, and possibly also some method of viewing them (although if it starts working, you can probably call it done). Depending on how they got there, you may also need to avoid using the same method in the future, or change settings so the U+200B characters don't get generated.

Comment: The asker also said "I retyped whole code still no success"

Comment: let me retype it all again again and thank you for your answer

Comment: Thank you it worked I did some research and retyped all the code again